# Rails 3.1 + jQuery Mobile + Testing in Desktop Safari = refresh will break style

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I am following this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices to implement mobile version of my site. I am using the jQuery Mobile instead of jQtouch.

For development testing, I am using desktop version of safari and changing the user agent to iPhone. However, whenever I hit refresh on some pages, jQuery Mobile will not be loaded and there are no styling applied. I need to go back to the previous page and click the link again to see the mobile version.

I suspect that it has to do with caching, but I could not figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/speed/page-speed/), try disabling it.